# How to iterate from last to first an ArrayList?

Tags: java, iterator, iteration

I wonder if is possible to iterate from last to the first element in an ArrayList, if so how? The reason is because I need to remove the last element added to the list

Comment: Why don't you just `list.remove(list.size() - 1)`?

Comment: How about looking at List's api documentation. Looking for "iterator" in the doc should help.

Comment: Fair but the reason I ask is because I was having problems using foreach and change my code to using while and hasNext Iterator combo so I wanted to change my code to something more robust, if that makes sense

Comment: You can't modify the contents of an array using a for each loop.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

While you can always iterate your `ArrayList` using an index, like this

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
... add code to populate the list with some data...
for (int i = myList.size() - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i--) {
    if (myList.get(i).equals("delete me")) {
        myList.remove(i);
    }
}
```

you would be better off using a `ListIterator<T>` for the purpose of deleting items from your `ArrayList`:

```
ListIterator<String> listIter = myList.listIterator();
while (listIter.hasNext()) {
    if (listIter.next().equals("delete me")) {
        listIter.remove();
    }
}
```

List iterators can be used to iterate your list backwards, too -- like this:

```
ListIterator<String> listIter = myList.listIterator(myList.size());
while (listIter.hasPrevious()) {
    String prev = listIter.previous();
    // Do something with prev here
}
```

The initial index of the iterator should be equal to the index of the last element + 1. As the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#listIterator(int)) say: "An initial call to `previous` would return the element with the specified index minus one."

Comment: But doesn't this option goes from first to last? I need to remove the elements from last to first in the best way possible, less prone to errors

Comment: @RicardoSanchez comment was posted 10 minutes ago on this question with a 1 liner that removes the last element. If that's not enough, perhaps you need to sharpen your requirement

Comment: The last code worked for me without the "-1" inside the listIterator() method: "myList.listIterator(myList.size());"

With the "-1" the interator was ignoring the latest item, starting from the penultimate.

Answer (score 8):

Here is one way to do it (your reason why is a separate question):

```
import java.util.*;

List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("a");
list.add("b");
list.add("c");

ListIterator<String> iter = list.listIterator(list.size());

while (iter.hasPrevious()) {
    String s = iter.previous();
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to just remove the last element of an array list, you could just do:

```
arrayList.remove(arrayList.size()-1);
```

If you wanted to remove all elements from back to front, you could use this for loop:

```
for(int i = arraList.size()-1; i >= 0; i--)
{
       arrayList.remove(i);
}
```

For more infomation on Array Lists, you can go here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_arraylist_class.htm

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList aList = new ArrayList();
aList.add(1);
aList.add(2);
aList.add(3);

Collections.reverse(aList);

Iterator iter = aList.iterator();
while(iter.hasNext()){
    iter.next();
    iter.remove();//remove an element
    break;//break from the loop or something else
}
```

Comment: That doesn't iterate from the end to the beginning. It reverses the collection, then iterates from the beginning. It's not only destructive, but also very inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> names = ....
int count= names.getSize();
Iterator<String> i = names.iterator();
while (i.hasNext()) {
   String s = i.next(); // must be called before you can call i.remove()
   // Do something
   if (count==1)
      i.remove();
   count--;
}
```